# Open Python shell through SSH

Tags: python, shell, ssh

I'm using [this](http://sshwindows.sourceforge.net/) tool to set up a ssh server on Windows. I'm trying to open the standard Python shell through a remote ssh connection but I simply can't get it to work. If I type 'python' in my ssh command line nothing happens, it just seems to wait for more input. My server machine however, shows a new python process running after I do this.

Running scripts works fine, though.

Do I need to use another Python shell, some other ssh server, some different configs?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that Python is not recognising the stdin on the SSH shell as a terminal. I don't know why that would be.

However, try running "python -i" to overcome it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably that you're running the Windows Python executable, which expects a Windows console environment to run in, over a channel which doesn't support the features of Windows console.  You might find Andy Koppe's [conin](http://groups.google.com/group/mintty-discuss/browse_thread/thread/1f9cf480117b8a0b) to be useful.